# Opt / Private Folder visible on HD?

Tags: finder, folders, macos

for some reason my /opt /private folders are not hidden anymore while the rest of my finder's hidden files are.  What would cause these to be visible again, and how do I change them back?  I know it has something to do with permissions, or fixing it might involve using "chflags"command.

**update:** so I fixed it after some searching around by using *chflags*

> sudo chflags hidden /opt /private

though Im still curious what caused these files to change.  Do you think it would have anything to do with developer tools or SDKs? I recently installed a bunch for mobile testing/development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This little ditty might help...

```
for ff in '/Network /Volumes /bin /cores  /etc 
  /mach /mach_kernel /private /sbin /tmp /usr /var '
do
   sudo chflags hidden $ff
done
```

You'll want to add in `/opt` if you added that and any other non-standard directories in `/` you wish to hide from the GUI.

As to why - you might need to track that down using fs_usage, but typically it's an installer that brute forces permissions or otherwise removed the metadata flags from those files.